# How to link to a specific list view from a list web part's title link

Tags: web-part, list-view, view

When I place a list's web part on a page and set it to a specific view, upon clicking the list title of that web part I am taken to the AllItems view of the actual list. I want to be able to see the view I set it to on the web part page. Is there a way to link it properly? I could use javascript to overwrite the link but hoping there is a better way. I am using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

Comment: Do you have access to SharePoint Designer? If so, you can modify the view link by editing the page in designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your browser and click the arrow to modify the web part. Expand the Advanced Section and replace the Title URL with your desired URL.